# Два лишних блока в дизайне

Tags: html, css

Собственно, не могу понять, откуда взялись два лишних блока в дизайне.

Ребята выручайте, два дня уже голову ломаю, никак найти не могу.
Пациент http://prob.obmenniki.pp.ua/

Дивы на скрине, они замещают ссылки, а их не надо ((( [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поменяй строку 230 в css на 
    #slides {
        position: absolute;
        top: 5px;
        left: 4px;
        z-index: 100;
        height: 100%;
    }

Это просто  slides  опускается вниз.  `height: 100%;` Спасет)

Comment: Спасибо большое, год бы искал!